# Xcode doesn't find CocoaPods module

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, arm64, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using the `CocoaAsyncSocket` library for an application I am writing.
When I compile and run it on my own device there's no problem and Xcode is able to find `CocoaAsyncSocket`.

However when I'm trying to Archive it won't compile and I get the error message that the module `CocoaAsyncSocket` can't be found.

I've noticed that it has something to do with the different architectures. When I build for my own device its only building for "arm64" and when I'm archiving its building for `arm64`,`armv7` and `armv7s`. If I change the build settings for archiving to only build for `arm64` I'm able to archive. But of course I want to be able to build it for all architectures.
Picture below displays settings for when its only building for `arm64` (in my case);

`Build Active Architecture Only: Yes`

[image]

Has anyone else experienced similar problems with this library or other Cocoapod libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers have embraced the impending 64-bit future but not all third party libraries support this architecture yet, including those installable via `CocoaPods`.

Despite the lack of universal 64-bit support among 3rd-party pods, CocoaPods still includes the arm64 architecture (via `ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT`) in its generated targets’ build settings. This can cause problems if your app’s dependencies don’t support arm64, or you only want to build for armv7 and armv7s for other reasons.

You can fix this just add the following to the bottom of your `Podfile` to revert the `ARCHS` build setting to `ARCHS_STANDARD`:

```
# Remove 64-bit build architecture from Pods targets
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      target.build_settings(configuration.name)['ARCHS'] = '$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)'
    end
  end
end
```

Note :

> [CocoaPods Troubleshooting Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html#running-into-build-failures-after-migrating-to-xcode--and-cocoapods-) recommends matching the Debug setting in your Xcode project, rather than changing the Pod's Build Active Architecture Only. As long as they match it seems to fix the problem.

1. Select the Pods project
2. Change Build Active Architecture Only from Yes to No.

Or

You can try updating `cocoapods` in your terminal using command:

`gem update cocoapods`

If it doesn't work after that, go into your workspace, click on the Pod project, select all Pod targets and set Architectures to (`armv7 armv7s arm64`).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, the version in the Podfile is good

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Comment: Oh dear, my project's deployment target was out of sync with the platform set in the Podfile, causing the Pods target to be ignored. Thank you!